# convert pointer to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers

I have some library code (I cannot not change the source code) that returns a pointer to an object (B).  I would like to store this pointer as shared_ptr under a class with this type of constructor:

```
class A
{
  public:
   A(boost::shared_ptr<B> val);
   ...
  private:
   boost::shared_ptr<B> _val;
   ...
};

int main()
{
   B *b = SomeLib();
   A a(b); //??
   delete b;
   ...
}
```

That is, I would like to make a deep-copy of b and control its life-time under a (even if original b is deleted (delete b), I still have an exact copy under a).

I'm new to this, sorry if it seems trivial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you have to copy them not just copy a pointer. So either B already has implemented 'clone' method or you have to implement some external `B* copy(B* b)` which will create new B with same state.

In case B has implemented copy constructor you can implement copy as just

```
B* copyOf(B* b)
{
    return new B(*b);
}
```

In case B has implemented [clone method or similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) you can implement copy as

```
B* copyOf(B* b)
{
    return b->clone();
}
```

and then your code will look like

```
int main()
{
   B *b = SomeLib();
   A a(copyOf(b));
   delete b;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see the use of the function `copy` …

Comment: second line in the main function.

Comment: @Mykola: I see it – but I don't get it: it simply makes no sense. Sorry.

Comment: The code now do what the question is asked. It makes B to accept just pointers. So If you want you pass a copy if don't you pass a pointer. If you make B to copy pointer in constructor you limit functionality of B.

Comment: I've changed 'copy' to 'copyOf' to emphasize that it is a function.

Answer (score 2):

If the library defines this B object, the library should provide (or outright prohibit) the mechanism for copying B.

As a sidenote,

If your class A is exclusively controlling the lifetime of this copied object, the smart pointer you really want to use is `boost::scoped_ptr`.

`boost::shared_ptr` is named after its ability to share lifetime responsibility, which it sounds like you don't want.  `scoped_ptr` won't let that accidentally happen.

Comment: Or just a member of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Deep-copying is implemented trivially in C++ by the copy constructor since in C++, *all* objects have value semantics by default. Copying in such a way doesn't work for polymorphous objects though – in such cases, you'd have to implement a virtually overridden `clone` method in your class.

But in all other cases, simply writing

```
A(boost::shared_ptr<B> val) : _val(new B(*val)) { }
```

will do.

Comment: +1. I don't see any reason to downvote your answer. On the contrary.

Comment: Mykola: what raw pointer? That's not possible here. This answer is completely correct.

Comment: First of all - I didn't minus you and just warn. Here is the warning: If B creates some objects inside and store them to use and B hasn't implemented copy constructor, default copy constructor will just copy pointers to the objects and not the objects, thus in destructor each B will delete the same data.

Comment: Mykola: well, true – this is defined and expected behaviour in C++ and it's B's job to provide an appropriate copy constructor, if needed. However, this never invalidates my above code (which is idiomatic C++). It just means B might have a bug.

Comment: True, as I said - it is just a warn to save Answerer time in the future.

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev - do you give that warning every time you see a C++ sample that involves copying an object? That must keep you busy!